# Node request package encodes querystring with [object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've seen similar issues with other javascript libraries, but none addressing this specific package.  I'm using the node Request library (Node version 8.0.0, request version 2.83.0).  I'm trying to add a querystring to the request, it encodes the querystring with `[object%20Object]` in the path.  Here's the exact code for the request:

```
request=require('request')
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8091/',
    qs: {param1:'value1', param2:'value2'},
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  },
  function(err, resp){
    console.log(resp)
  }
);
```

And here's a snippet from the output (it's really long, so I'm only pasting in a relevant portion).

```
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /?param1=value1[object%20Object]param2=value2 HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-type: application/json\r\nhost: localhost:8091\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/?param1=value1[object%20Object]param2=value2',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     ntick: true,
     response: [Circular],
     originalHost: 'localhost:8091',
     originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
     responseContent: [Circular],
     _destdata: true,
     _ended: true,
     _callbackCalled: true },
  toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
  caseless: 
   Caseless {
     dict: 
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': '140',
        date: 'Mon, 30 Oct 2017 14:37:30 GMT',
        connection: 'close' } },
  read: [Function],
  body: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n' }
```

Notice how in multiple places, such as the `path` field, it says `'/?param1=value1[object%20Object]param2=value2'`.  As far as I can tell, I'm submitting the query parameters correctly.  Why is it adding the `[object%20Object]`?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your server is sending this sort of response. Can you confirm that is not the case?

Comment: Why are you passing the data in a query string when you are making a POST request? Why are you saying the content-type of the body is JSON when you aren't passing a body?

Comment: because somebody else wrote this api and did a less-than-stellar job.  I tried removing the `Content-Type` header and it still didn't work

Comment: By the way, I can confirm with a good 'ol curl request that the server is capable of accepting these arguments.  So I'm sure the problem is with this library, not the server receiving the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a workaround.  Rather than trying to put querystrings into the `qs` parameter, I just put it directly into the URL directly.  Like this:

```
request=require('request')
querystring = require('querystring')
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8091/?' + querystring.stringify({ param1:'value1', param2:'value2' }),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  },
  function(err, resp){
    console.log(resp)
  }
);
```

That's a huge bug that perhaps we should fix.  A warning to anyone else using the *request* library.  **DON'T USE THE "QS" FIELD TO SPECIFY YOUR QUERY STRING.  IF YOU SUPPLY MORE THAN ONE PARAMETER IT WILL NOT WORK.**

Comment: I can also recommend using the Fetch API (node-fetch package). It behaves a bit more sane, as it follows the new Fetch standard.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

{param1:'value1',param2:'value2'},

See that I removed the space between the two parameters. It is a very long shot and if this is the problem is an awful bug.